# AJAX request when passing JSON string

Tags: ajax, json

I've got a code:

```
    function fetchFacets() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();

    var ne = bounds.getNorthEast();
    var sw = bounds.getSouthWest();

    var req ={ match_all: {} };

    var f = 1 - zoom2digits[map.zoom] / 12;
    $.ajax({

        url: "http://146.185.164.121:9200/fnh_main/main/_search?size=0",
        contentType: "text/json",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            query: {
                filtered: {
                    query: {
                        req,
                    },
                    filter: {
                        geo_bounding_box: {
                            location : {
                                top_left : ne.lat()+","+sw.lng(),
                                bottom_right : sw.lat()+","+ne.lng()
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
    facets : {
        places : { 
            geohash : {
                field : "location",
                factor : f,
                show_geohash_cell: true
            }
        }
    }
}
        ), dataType: "json"}
).done..............
```

I need to pass it like this:

```
filtered: {
                        query: {
                            match_all: {}
                        },
```

What am i doing wrong? I get an error that } is unexpected, but everithing works fine when I enter match_all: {} manually. Please help!

Update: Added some more code.

Comment: request variable is just a string, not an object. you need to turn that string into an object by parsing it with JSON parser

Comment: It is hard to tell from your example if you truly have balanced your brackets

Comment: How can it be done via jquery maybe...can you please give advise(

Comment: following on from @dbrin great answer **var request = {}; request["match_all"]={};** will give you a dynamic parameter

Comment: Sico, sorry, no luck with this... Maybe I get something wrong, but i tried the provided code and it gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var request = {  match_all: {} };

$.ajax({

    url: "http://146.185.164.121:9200/fnh_main/main/_search?size=0",
    contentType: "text/json",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        query: {
            filtered: {
                query:  request,
```

Comment: can you post the rest of your code - you probably have a few issues

Comment: you need to pay attention to detail here. query: {
                        req,
                    }, is not correct. It needs to be query:
                        req,